# Defining styles in ganttchart

Tags: pgfgantt

I know I can define a new ganttbar to customize a bar (for repeated use) as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\newganttchartelement{mybar}{
mybar height=.2,
mybar top shift=.4,
mybar/.append style={fill=red,yshift=.1cm}}

\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,hgrid]{1}{12}
  \ganttmybar{Test}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttmybar{Test2}{3}{6}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

But I am wondering if I can use custom styles instead, so that I can do something like this:

```
\ganttbar[mine]{Test}{1}{2}
```

I tried adding the following in `ganttchart` to define the style:

```
mine height=.2,
mine top shift=.4,
mine/.append style={fill=red,yshift=.1cm}
```

but that didn't work (I received several errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom styles in the following way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,hgrid,bar height=.2,bar top shift=.4,
    mine/.style={bar/.append style={
        draw=blue, rounded corners=3pt, dashed, thick, fill=red, yshift=.2cm
    }}]{1}{12}
  \ganttbar[mine]{Test}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttbar{Test2}{3}{6}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, `bar height` and `top shift` cannot be customized in the style, they are defined for all bars.